# スクリプトをアタッチできない

Tags: c#

ゲームオブジェクトにスクリプトをアタッチしようとするとこういうエラーがでます。

```
Can`t add script

Can`t add script behaviour Assmblyinfo.cs. The script
needs to derive from MonoBehaviour!
```

Windows 7
Unity 2018.4.24f1

Comment: 参考になりそうな資料　https://answers.unity.com/questions/406899/the-script-needs-to-derive-from-monobehaviour.html

Comment: 上記資料によると原因となりうるものが複数ありそうです。書ける範囲で質問をもうすこし詳細に書いていただくことは可能でしょうか。（もしくは上記サイトを参考に自己解決した場合はご自身で回答も書けるはずです）

Comment: 解決していないが同件らしきもの。[Unityの“Can't add script”のエラーの解決策](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/62463/26370), [スクリプトがオブジェクトにアタッチ出来ない](https://teratail.com/questions/128536) 古いけれどヒントになるかもしれないもの。[\[Unity\]"Can't add script behavior XXXX.The script needs to derive from MonoBehaviour"の改善方法4つ](https://qiita.com/riekure/items/90cc2aa26460daf1d75a), [Unity・アタッチエラーの対処](http://necoroneko.blog.fc2.com/blog-entry-16.html)

Comment: クラス名のところは　.cs　は必要ですか？

Comment: Reimport AllするっていうのをしてみたところCan`t add script behaviour Assmblyinfo.cs. The script
needs to derive from MonoBehaviour!のAssmblyinfo.cs. のところがCallback Executor.になりました。Can`t add script behaviour Callback Executor. The script
needs to derive from MonoBehaviour!

Comment: これまでは、project　windowのCreate からC#スクリプトを作ってオブジェクトにアタッチしていましたが、オブジェクトのInspector　windowのAdd ComponentからNew script でスクリプトを作るとオブジェクトにスクリプトをつけることができました

Answer (score 0):

UnityのオブジェクトやPrefabにアタッチできるのは、
ScriptableObject　または MonoBehaviour　を継承（祖先に持つ）したクラスになります。

Unityエンジンは、
これらを目印に、Awake、Start、Update、FixedUpdateといった特定タイミングで呼び出される関数をダックタイピング認識して呼び出します。

※　Unityでスクリプトを書き始める上で、
一番最初に学ぶことなので、初心者本にも丁寧に解説していると思います。
Unityの教科書　か　UnityではじめるC#　あたりがおすすめです。